# I want a better way of writing SQL that gets all comments from comments table, belonging to a particular article in articles table

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, postgresql

I have an articles table with  PK_articleid, and comments table with FK_articleid which references the articles table. I want to be able to get all the comments that belong to a particular article. See table below:

[image: articles table]

[image: comments table]

So far, i am able to get required columns with INNER JOIN, but i want a way to access the comments object properties like in the "What i want" sample object below.

```
const text = 'SELECT a.articleid, a.createdon, a.title, a.article, c.id, c.comment, c.authorid  
FROM articles a INNER JOIN comments c ON a.articleid = c.articleid';

    exports.getArticleAndComments = (request, response) => {

      pool.query(text, (error, res) => {
        if (error) {
          // throw error
          console.log(`not able to get connection ${error}`);
          response.status(400).json({
            status: 'error',
            error: error.stack,
          });
        }
        response.status(200).json({
          status: 'success',
          data: {
            id: res.rows[0].articleid,
            createdon: res.rows[0].createdon,
            title: res.rows[0].title,
            article: res.rows[0].article,
            comments: res.rows
          },
        });
      });
    };
```

What i want:

```
"data" : {
    "id" : Integer ,
    "createdOn" : DateTime ,
    "title" : String ,
    "article" : String ,
    "comments" : [
      {
        "commentId" : Integer ,
        "comment" : String ,
        "authorId" : Integer ,
      } ,
      {
        "commentId" : Integer ,
        "comment" : String ,
        "authorId" : Integer ,
      } ,
    ]
  }
```

What i get:

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "data": {
    "id": 21,
    "createdon": "2019-11-13T19:41:51.613Z",
    "title": "The gods must be crazy",
    "article": "An article about crazy gods",
    "comments": [
      {
        "articleid": 21,
        "createdon": "2019-11-13T19:41:51.613Z",
        "title": "The gods must be crazy",
        "article": "An article about crazy gods",
        "commentId": 28,
        "comment": "The gods have always been crazy",
        "authorid": 106
      },
      {
        "articleid": 21,
        "createdon": "2019-11-13T19:41:51.613Z",
        "title": "The gods must be crazy",
        "article": "An article about crazy gods",
        "commentId": 27,
        "comment": "Unleash the dragon",
        "authorid": 106
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Uwem, this seems like nodejs which is not my forte but you may want to add some information about what library and database you are using. The more specific the easier to get some answers.

Comment: The query returns comments for all articles, not just a single article. Why are you extracting the article information from the first row out of the `comments` array?

Comment: if you want to get comments for a specific article, you need `WHERE a.articleid = ?` in the query.

Comment: So are you saying you are getting more data than you want? The only difference I can see is in the names and number of columns. If that is the case then simply change your query to only return what you want, and your code to only read the data you want, named as you want.

Comment: @Barmar with LEFT JOIN, the query returns comments for all articles until i use INNER JOIN. It isn't robust as you can see since i have to extract the article, without extracting, it returns the same article for every comment. Perhaps a JOIN isn't ideal here.

Comment: @juanotto, i'm using PostgreSQL pg library for Nodejs. I only thought it had more to do with SQL query than code.

Comment: @TomC Exactly, i am getting more data than i want in the comments array. To extract with res.rows[0].comment returns a single row as it were, while res.rows returns all data as seen here, which isn't what i want in the comment array. I guess the devil is in the query itself.

Comment: @UwemUke yeah, I got it afterwards. Did you try my answer? Comment there if something else is needed.

Comment: @UwemUke `LEFT JOIN` will include articles with no comments, the columns from the `comments` table will be `NULL`. Both `INNER JOIN` and `OUTER JOIN` will return all comments, because there's nothing filtering the article IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the best way of doing it but the closest to your code (so, less changes)

```
const text = 'SELECT a.articleid, a.createdon, a.title, a.article, c.id, c.comment, c.authorid  
FROM articles a INNER JOIN comments c ON a.articleid = c.articleid
WHERE a.articleid = YOUR_ARTICLE_ID_HERE';

exports.getArticleAndComments = (request, response) => {

  pool.query(text, (error, res) => {
    if (error) {
      // throw error
      console.log(`not able to get connection ${error}`);
      response.status(400).json({
        status: 'error',
        error: error.stack,
      });
    }
    response.status(200).json({
      status: 'success',
      data: {
        id: res.rows[0].articleid,
        createdon: res.rows[0].createdon,
        title: res.rows[0].title,
        article: res.rows[0].article,
        comments: res.rows.map((row) => {return {
          commentId: row.commentId,
          comment: row.comment,
          authorId: row.authorId,
        }})
      },
    });
  });
};
```

You said you want the info that "belong to a particular article", replace the article id at the end of the query for that (YOUR_ARTICLE_ID_HERE).

Comment: This works well for me. Though somewhat hacky, i will accept it if i can't come up with a better query statement within the next hour. Thanks.

Comment: Cool, good to know it works. A better approach would be to have two queries: one for the article, one for the comments, so you don't have to split the results on the response. That needs more work to handle the response status but it would be way more clear.

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand, you need to get the table **attributes** not the stored data.
In postgres, the way to get table attributes(col names & data types) is to query the information schema as per there docs https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-columns.html

Comment: I think the datatypes in his desired output were just placeholders, he actually wants the data.